# Selenium throwing 'no display specified' error when one exists

Tags: eclipse, firefox, selenium, rhel, rtc

I have a script that starts a Selenium server (if one is not already running) and then runs some acceptance tests in Codeception (with Firefox version 27, which is compatible with our Selenium 2.42.2). If I go onto the server (using VNC), the script runs and executes properly, however I'm using eclipse with RTC plugin, and it's set up so that you can make a build request, which will run that script on the server.

For some reason it always fails with this error (or some variant of it):

```
15:42:26.125 WARN - Exception: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified
```

On the server, even if I manually do export DISPLAY, it still fails from RTC. As far as I can tell, there's nothing special in the build rules that would cause this. It it just because VNC happens to be a GUI, and it can't find a display from just a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that there is not graphical interface available for user(as it probably use ssh to connect), I would suggest you to use [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

Comment: Installed Xvfb and modified my scripts a bit to use it, seems to work so far. Thanks!